# Pure JS // Hide div when another divs class has been changed

Tags: javascript, triggers, show-hide

Note: I can't use jQuery, only vanilla javascript

I'm not really fluent in pure JS. And this time I can't use any external resources (like jquery).

---

**What I need:**

> If div1 class is active, hide text2
>
> If div2 class is active, hide text1

I made it somehow to work, but my JS doesn't trigger when the class changes dynamic with another javascript code.

**Code that triggers the active class**

```
function activeClass(elem) {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('item')
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].classList.remove('active')
  }
  elem.classList.add('active');
}
```

**Code that should trigger hide/show when the class changes**

```
if (document.querySelector(".text2").classList.contains("active")) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('text1s')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementsByClassName('text2s')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
}

if (document.querySelector(".text1").classList.contains("active")) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('text2s')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementsByClassName('text1s')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

What did I do wrong?

---

**[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMqJpQ)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Place your conditions inside click handler.
- Add inline `visibility` style for `inactive` element

```js
function activeClass(elem) {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('item')
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].classList.remove('active')
  }
  elem.classList.add('active');
  if (document.querySelector(".text2").classList.contains("active")) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('text1s')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementsByClassName('text2s')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  if (document.querySelector(".text1").classList.contains("active")) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('text2s')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementsByClassName('text1s')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 3em;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
a {
  padding: 10px;
}
.active {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a class="item text1" onclick="activeClass(this)">show text</a>
<a class="item text2 active" onclick="activeClass(this)">hide text</a>
<br>
<br>
<h1 class="text1s" style='visibility:hidden;'>TEXT 1</h1>
<h1 class="text2s">TEXT 2</h1>
```

### [**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOxpoX)

Comment: @ekclone, I'm glad to help you!

Comment: quick question, how should I do it that it would allow 2 divs with the same class to trigger the same code? right now, only the first div triggers the code, not the second. Is it an array problem?

Comment: @ekclone You are considering first element from NodeList by [0].. Use a loop instead..

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm using a loop